# Mapbox: Is there a way to retrieve all coordinates for a specific feature ID?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm building a feature where I need to extract all coordinates of a selecetd road/path in Mapbox when it's clicked on. I've attempted to use the queryRenderedFeatures method, but it seems the result list is fragmented. By "fragmented" I mean that if you have a road or path which is clearly just one long path/road when rendered on the map, it often consists up of 4-5-6 or more features, and you cannot really work out from the feature collection how they're supposed to be connected (in order)

I then tried to use the Tilequery API, but it doesn't return any coordinates for LineStrings.

Is there any API - server or client side - in Mapbox, where you can provide an ID of a feature and retrieve the all coordinates for a road or path?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really asking: "is there a way to access complete LineString features for data in Mapbox's tilesets", to which the answer is, no, not really - other than trying to reassemble them in the way you have tried.

For your own data, you could host it using Mapbox's Datasets, rather than Tilesets.

Comment: Yes, that might be a better way of phrasing it :-) And even if it wasn't the answer I was hoping for, thanks for confirming I'll have to do make some work-around